# Displaying WordPress posts on an HTML page

Tags: wordpress

I have a hybrid website that consists of two integrated parts - a one-page HTML section and a WordPress-built blog. I would like to create a section on the HTML page where 6 blog articles will be displayed randomly. For SEO reasons, the display of author, categories, and tags has been removed from the blog. There is an API connection to WordPress, but an error message appears when accessing http://sagojs.webd.pro/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=6&orderby=rand. It seems that disabling these options is causing an error. As a result, the expected effect on the webpage is not achieved. However, I'm unsure whether the error stems from blocking the author, categories, and tags or if it lies within the script itself. As I am not a programmer, I am unable to solve this problem on my own. Please help.

The code I've used consists of parts in JavaScript and PHP:

```
<script>
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://sagojs.webd.pro/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=6&orderby=rand";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var posts = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      var html = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        html += "<div>";
        html += "<h2>" + posts[i].title.rendered + "</h2>";
        html += "<p>" + posts[i].content.rendered + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
      }

      document.getElementById("post-module").innerHTML = html;
    }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

```
<?php
  $url = "http://sagojs.webd.pro/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=6&orderby=rand";
  $response = file_get_contents($url);
  $posts = json_decode($response);

  foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "<div>";
    echo "<h2>" . $post->title->rendered . "</h2>";
    echo "<p>" . $post->content->rendered . "</p>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

The space to display posts:
`<div id="post-module"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I think your rest api isnt enabled. If i for example visit http://sagojs.webd.pro/wp-json/wp/v2 it gives a 404.
Please check if your hosting has restrictions and if you are using a security plugin that might block it.

Comment: Yes, that's my mistake. It should be http://sagojs.webd.pro/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=6&orderby=rand

Comment: I think a simple test will now do. Adjust the url and activate authors etc. once for indexation. Now test the url again and see if errors keep on being displayed. If not, you know the root of the problem.